# Ошибка type mismatch при записи данных в файл

Tags: pascal

Помогите с паскалем. Записываю данные в файл, но получаю ошибку "type mismatch".
В чём проблема?

```
...
var f_in:text;
data1:array[1..20,1..7] of string[30];
f_data:file of string[30];
i,k,v,h,e,o,n,j:integer;
s:string;
label again;
begin
assign(f_in,'c:\dieta\in.txt');
assign(f_data,'c:\dieta\out.dat');
reset (f_in);
i:=1;

...

rewrite(f_data);
for i:=1 to k do begin
s:=data1[i,1];
write(f_data,s); <--------------------------------------тут ошибка
end;
close(f_data);
reset(f_data);
while not eof(f_data) do begin
read(f_data,s);
writlen(s);
end;
close(f_data);

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробовать объявить

```
s:string[30];
```